# pd.read_htmlがうまく機能しない

Tags: python3, pandas

以下のURLからテーブルデータを取ろうとしていますが、片方のURLの場合(aa1)だけうまくいきません。
これは取ってくるデータの文字列に何か原因があるのでしょうか。また、色々他のサイトで調べた結果、encoding="cp932"と行ってもうまくいきませんでした。
例えば、

```
import pandas as pd
aa0 = "https://db.netkeiba.com/race/201901010101"
pd.read_html(aa0)
```

出力は

```
    [   着順  枠番  馬番         馬名  性齢  斤量    騎手     タイム     着差     単勝  人気       馬体重  \
 0   1   1   1      ゴルコンダ  牡2  54  ルメール  1:48.3    NaN    1.4   1  518(-16)   
 1   2   3   3   プントファイヤー  牡2  54  岩田康誠  1:50.1      大    3.5   2   496(-8)   
 2   3   4   4  ラグリマスネグラス  牡2  51  団野大成  1:50.9      5   46.6   6   546(+6)   
 3   4   8   9     キタノコドウ  牡2  51  菅原明良  1:51.5  3.1/2   56.8   7   458(-8)   
 4   5   5   5   ネモフィラブルー  牡2  54  川島信二  1:51.7  1.1/2  140.3   9    436(0)   
 5   6   8   8  マイネルラクスマン  牡2  54  丹内祐次  1:52.1  2.1/2    9.7   3   480(+8)   
 6   7   2   2    サンモンテベロ  牝2  54   黛弘人  1:52.5  2.1/2  114.7   8   450(+2)   
 7   8   7   7   エスカレーション  牝2  54  藤岡佑介  1:52.5    アタマ   26.1   5   448(-4)   
 8   9   6   6   セイウンジュリア  牝2  54  池添謙一  1:52.6     クビ   16.4   4    470(0)   
 
         調教師  
 0  [東] 木村哲也  
 1  [東] 手塚貴久  
 2  [東] 藤沢和雄  
 3   [東] 高木登  
 4  [西] 矢作芳人  
 5  [東] 金成貴史  
 6  [東] 中野栄治  
 7  [東] 高柳瑞樹  
 8  [西] 浅見秀一  ,
     0      1          2    3
 0  単勝      1        140    1
 1  複勝    134  110110470  127
 2  枠連  1 - 3        190    1
 3  馬連  1 - 3        190    1,
      0                1           2      3
 0  ワイド  1 - 31 - 43 - 4  1208401100  11213
 1   馬単            1 → 3         290      1
 2  三連複        1 - 3 - 4        1610      6
 3  三連単        1 → 3 → 4        3560     10,
             0                                           1
 0        馬場指数    プレミアサービスにご加入して頂くと馬場指数が確認できます。プレミアサービス案内へ
 1  馬場コメント (?)  プレミアサービスにご加入して頂くと馬場コメントが確認できます。プレミアサービス案内へ,
        0                      1
 0  1コーナー     1(4,3)6(5,8)2(9,7)
 1  2コーナー   1(3,8)4,6-(5,7)(2,9)
 2  3コーナー  (*1,3)(4,8)6-5,2(9,7)
 3  4コーナー     1,3-(4,8)6-5(9,2)7,
      0                                                  1
 0  ラップ  12.5 - 11.5 - 11.9 - 11.7 - 12.0 - 12.2 - 12.4...
 1  ペース  12.5 - 24.0 - 35.9 - 47.6 - 59.6 - 71.8 - 84.2...]
```

同じように, aa1に渡したURLを読み込むと

```
aa1 = "https://db.netkeiba.com/race/202204010202"
pd.read_html(aa1)[0]
```

エラー

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3b6afaad857c> in <module>
      2 aa0 = "https://db.netkeiba.com/race/201901010101"
      3 aa1 = "https://db.netkeiba.com/race/202204010202"
----> 4 pd.read_html(aa1)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
   1083     io = stringify_path(io)
   1084 
-> 1085     return _parse(
   1086         flavor=flavor,
   1087         io=io,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    916     for table in tables:
    917         try:
--> 918             ret.append(_data_to_frame(data=table, **kwargs))
    919         except EmptyDataError:  # empty table
    920             continue

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _data_to_frame(**kwargs)
    795     # fill out elements of body that are "ragged"
    796     _expand_elements(body)
--> 797     with TextParser(body, header=header, **kwargs) as tp:
    798         return tp.read()
    799 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in TextParser(*args, **kwds)
   2227     """
   2228     kwds["engine"] = "python"
-> 2229     return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)
   2230 
   2231 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   2308                 self.num_original_columns,
   2309                 self.unnamed_cols,
-> 2310             ) = self._infer_columns()
   2311         except (TypeError, ValueError):
   2312             self.close()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _infer_columns(self)
   2721                 columns = [names]
   2722             else:
-> 2723                 columns = self._handle_usecols(columns, columns[0])
   2724         else:
   2725             try:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

となります。aa0,aa1のURLをweb上で直接叩いていただけると分かる通り、どちらも競馬の結果データが同じレイアウトで表示されています。しかし,aa1のURLだとうまくスクレイピングができていません。この理由がわからず、ご指摘お願いできますでしょうか。

Comment: 単に `pd.read_html(aa1)` と記述した場合はどうなりますか？ `aa0` と `aa1` はそれぞれ独立した変数のはずなので (= 配列ではない)、`pd.read_html(aa1)[0]` がどういった意図での記述なのかが分かりませんでした。

Comment: pandasを使って, htmlからテーブルをスクレイピングする場合は, pd.read_html(URL)[0]を使うのが基本のようです。問題点はそこではなく, 上記のurlにそれぞれアクセスでき、レイアウトも同じなのにどうしてaa1の場合は読み込めないのかわからないということです。

Comment: @cubick さん指摘の`pd.read_html(aa1)`とだけしてもエラーは発生しますね。`[0]`が付くのはページ内にいくつかある表の中で最初のレース結果の表だけ欲しいということでしょう。色々試してみると今月(2022年5月)の1日まではOKで7日以後はNGのようです。何かHTML等の構造が変わったのかもしれません。あるいは一時的な物とか、配信される広告が変わったとか、色々な可能性があるのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問内容をもう少しわかりやすく修正しました

Comment: 参考までに、Python 3.10.4/Pandas 1.4.2 で当該のエラーは発生しません。

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) では複数のテーブルを一度に読み込むので, 問題を切り分けるには一つずつ試すとよいかも。

頻繁に幾度もアクセスを試みるのは, サイトへの「攻撃」に繋がるので読み取るまでを区切りにします

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://db.netkeiba.com/race/201901010101'
url = 'https://db.netkeiba.com/race/202204010202'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

あとは, 1つずつ確認していくとよいでしょう

```py
lst = soup('table')
display(f'テーブル数: {len(lst)}')
for tbl in lst:
    try:
        dfs = pd.read_html(str(tbl))
        #if len(dfs) == 1:
        #    display(dfs[0])
    except:
        display(tbl)
```

問題箇所は, 4/6 番目のテーブルで内容が入って無さそうなところ
(一応, 内容は伏せておきます)